# AWS CLI encrypt the data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I´m using AWS cloud formation, and I could not find in any documentation information about this. When I use cloudformation with AWS CLI the information sent to AWS it´s encrypted?.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information is sent over HTTPS, so the communication between your client and AWS servers is secure. On the other hand, if you are providing sensitive information with parameters you can enable `NoEcho` parameter to prevent them from being displayed on AWS Console. The `NoEcho` property is set to true to prevent describe stack calls, such as the `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` AWS CLI command, from returning the parameter value

```
"Parameters" : {
  "DBPort" : {
    "Default" : "3306",
    "Description" : "TCP/IP port for the database",
    "Type" : "Number",
    "MinValue" : "1150",
    "MaxValue" : "65535"
  },
  "DBPwd" : {
    "NoEcho" : "true",
    "Description" : "The database admin account password",
    "Type" : "String",
    "MinLength" : "1",
    "MaxLength" : "41",
    "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
  }
}
```